# How to verify void method with the Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, static, mockito

I'm writing some `unitTest` for a class that its name is `NetworkRequest`.
In this class, I have a function that its name is `run`.

```
public void run(NetworkResponseListener listener) {
        if (listener == null)
            return;

        this.mListener = listener;

        CheckInternetAccess.checkInternetAccess(manager, new NetworkStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInternetResponse(int internetCode) {

                if (internetCode == ErrorCodes.CODE_HAS_INTERNET_ACCESS) {
                    runRequest();
                } else {
                    mListener.onNetworkResponse(null);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

I want to create a test when the input listener(`NetworkResponseListener`)
be null.

I wrote something like below:

```
public class NetworkRequestTest {

    private ReceivedRequest receivedRequest = Mockito.mock(ReceivedRequest.class);
    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = Mockito.mock(ConnectivityManager.class);
    private NetworkStateListener networkStateListener = Mockito.mock(NetworkStateListener.class);

    @Test
    public void checkInternetAccessShouldNotCallWithNullListener() {
        NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest(receivedRequest, connectivityManager);//SUT

        networkRequest.run(null);

        Mockito.verify(CheckInternetAccess.checkInternetAccess(connectivityManager, networkStateListener), Mockito.never());
    }
}
```

I want to check verification of `CheckInternetAccess.checkInternetAccess`
But I got an error that says:

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'void', required: 'java.lang.Void'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(...) on your mock objects.